# How to scale all components of an view?

Tags: ios, uikit, ios-autolayout, iphone-x, ios-universal-app

Is there any best way to scale all components (button, button title, image, all it's hierarchy sub-views) of a view according to device screen size such as iPhone XS, iPhone XS Max, iPhone X etc.

Actually, I have some screens in iOS app project which is designed on a particular iPhone all constraints are fixed so I need to change them according to other iPhone screen.

As I know that we can do this by applying some constraints with ratio and all other things like font and image scaling by programmatically but I am searching for a best and simple solution that takes less effort to me.

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at size class ? You can find plenty of documentation on the Internet.

Comment: @Balanced Thanks for reply , Yes I  know and also used it many times but in it frist we need to calculate all font, image sizes  according to the screen's so I am searching for another solution which calculate all things to me☺.

Comment: Please let me know why I am getting voted down for this question I just want to know the reason to improve my skills because I am new here, please comment me thanks in advance.

Comment: Scaling UI for different screen sizes sounds like waste of UI real estate. Just because someone uses a bigger screen doesn't mean they want to have the content scaled up. They rather want to see more content.

Comment: Thanks for replying, actually we know that in most of the cases we have same contents for all the iPhones and also it doesn't make sense to use different UI contents on different iPhones, yes they very if we use iPads in place of iPhones but all iPads also have same number of UI contents not different, also what if we don't have more contents(this is my case) so that's why I am searching for best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right this can be implemented by screen ratio, as I did this a year ago. Let me tell you, how you can do this-

You need to scale the image size, the font size of the text and also every constraint of every view according to screen ratio.

Have you ever try [ScalableLayoutKit](https://github.com/keshavvishwkarma/ScalableLayoutKit) library which is implemented by me to design scalable, consistent UI based on design/source screen.

For example:- Suppose you want to design a login screen according to `iPhone6 mock-up` for this you create a `LoginViewController` and design UI from Storyboard.

**Using ScalableLayoutKit**

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()      
        // Here we just need to passed based or source design screen name only.
        // This method will recursively scale your all ui elements and its constraints too.
        view.scaledLayoutDesign(from: .iPhone6)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to organize views in UIStackViews and set up stack views appropriately, so you don't have to worry much about your subviews

Comment: Thanks for reply but it would not work with sub-content like font of an ui-button title and also content with content specially when I have prepared ui.